# Include .rosinstall in a version-controlled repository?

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder whether it's useful to include the (in my case manually generated) .rosinstall file into my ROS package's GIT repository. If so, developers can just get the project via GIT and then call *rosinstall* and source one of the shell scripts in order to compile my project without hassle... Is there any drawback which I might have overlooked?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9439/include-.rosinstall-in-a-version-controlled-repository?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of including the .rosinstall file, it is a much better practice to include the original rosinstall file (no dot prefix).  The .rosinstall file encodes information about a specific installation on a specific machine.  The original rosinstall file can be safely used to generate any number of installations on multiple machines.

Most VCSs allow you to pull individual files by url.

Then you can write your install instructions like this:

```
rosinstall ~/my_project /opt/ros/diamondback 'http://my_vcs_server/path_to_file.rosinstall'
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on 2011-03-16**:
Thanks, I've implemented this solution. My rosinstall file now does not only include dependencies but also refers to the GIT repository of my own project. I like installation instructions that can be written in one single command-line.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-16**:
This is what we do.  With Github, you don't have to do a full checkout, instead use https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/raw/BRANCH/file.rosinstall